# tooltip not working in vis.js timeline

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I need a tooltip for each items the problem is that when I put for example :
`title:'<b>Hover over me<b></br>test'`the style is not applicated and so in the tooltip the result was `<b>Hover over me<b></br>test` not Hover over me  test.
I want to change the style of every title in the tooltip .
please have you any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Without some further information, it seems you are in the correct path.

As per documentation:

> title - string - "Add a title for the item, displayed when holding the mouse on the
>   item. The title can be an HTML element or a string containing plain
>   text or HTML."

Working sample below:

```
var data = new vis.DataSet([{
    id: 2,
    content: 'Pi and Mash',
    start: '2014-08-08',
    title: '<b> Bold title </b> <br> Not bold'
}, 
... 
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sm4r5pvc/

Answer (score 0):

Update vis version. In the older version, we don't have the tooltip. Make sure you are working with `v4.21.0` and above